# How do I use anything like Count_values on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I've filtered a database to just get people in India, then get their occupations, and I'd like to find the most common occupations.  I understand I can't use count_values, so I'm trying to use groupby instead

```
IN_occupations =df.loc[df['native-country']=='India', ['occupation']]
    top_IN_occupation = IN_occupations.groupby('occupation')
```

top_IN_occupation then prints out the following (which appears to be an empty dataframe)

`<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f3a69291e20>`

For those of you asking for more of the example please see here:https://repl.it/@SethAlan/boilerplate-demographic-data-analyzer#demographic_data_analyzer.py (you may need to run poetry install in console. I keep having to do that)

Comment: Please refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html
and to get a count , you can simply use ```top_IN_occupation.count()```

Comment: Using groupby() on a column will return an object. All you need is to apply an aggregation operation to the object to return a dataframe or a series

Comment: I am not sure why ```IN_occupations.value_counts()``` is not working, may you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I've added a link to my repl in the original post if that helps.  Appreciate your help here!  I'm not sure what you mean by aggregation operation?  still relatively new to this.  Can you give me an example of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your code and value_counts() works exactly how it should be. Not sure if you have already fixed it and I am also getting "Prof-specialty" as the top occupation in India with salary '>50K'

```
# Identify the most popular occupation for those who earn >50K in India.
    IN_occupations = df.loc[(df['native-country']=='India') & (df['salary']=='>50K'), ['occupation']]
    
    
    top_IN_occupation = IN_occupations['occupation'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Was able to fix it thanks to your original comments!

Comment: No worries mate. Glad I helped.